# Complex SELECT Query Format for C# Form

Tags: c#, sql, select-query

I have a table with the following columns:

```
SupplierId
SupplierBillID
SupplierDate
Supplierparticulars
SupplierCredit
SupplierDebit
```

Now, the problem is that earlier I had only 1 particulars in 1 bill. Now I have more particulars in the bill and since the application is running for a long time I am not in a condition to change it. What it shows right now is like:

```
SupplierBillID  SupplierParticulars       SupplierCredit      SupplierDebit
17                 Pipes                      1500                   0
17                 Tubes                       500                   200
17                 Wire                       1000                   500
```

But instead I want it to show like:

```
17                 **See Details**               3000                   700
```

Now this "See Details" thing I can set in gridviewCellclick event to show the details of that bill and all particulars.

Comment: I would like to add that forget that see details thing in the particulars place, leave it, I want to see only totals of the bill to be displayed as according to table structure.. Kindly help

Comment: if you think you forgot to mention something, feel free to edit your question. Comments might go un-noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select SupplierBillID, 'See Details', sum(SupplierCredit), sum(SupplierDebit)
from your_table
group by SupplierBillID
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the code above, removed the fields of particulars, date and took only BillID, Credit and Debit to be displayed in datagridview and added a Button to each row with "See Details" and activating a form to display all details of that bill only..